# Given an APK file, is it possible to know if it's a part of a split APK files, or a stand-alone?

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

### Background

Sometimes when you backup some APK file of an app, you'd notice that they consist of multiple APK files, meaning split APK files (AKA app-bundle).

### The problem

I want to know, when someone sends the user an APK file, if indeed it's a standalone one, or is a part of split APK files. The reason is a different procedure and even a warning of such a thing, because split APK files are not really meant to be installed as normal ones.

### What I've tried

Given `PackageManager` class ([**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager)), I couldn't find a way for [**getPackageArchiveInfo**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageArchiveInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)) to get this kind of information.

There is `splitNames` and `splitRevisionCodes` , but both are just null.

### My question

Is it possible, given a single APK file, to check if it's a part of multiple split APK files?

---

EDIT: so thanks to [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56093643/878126), I've found how to do it for the main APK of the split APK files ("base.APK") :

```
    val packageInfo = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
    val isSplit = packageInfo.applicationInfo.metaData.getBoolean("com.android.vending.splits.required", false)
```

But, as for the rest of the split apk files, using `getPackageArchiveInfo` on them will just return null. I can't find how to parse the manifest of them to find the "split" attribute.

So my question now is:

Given the rest of the split APK files, how can I parse them to check they are indeed split APK files , which belong to the base.APK file?

Comment: Thanks for adding the solution. It helped alot.